# Creating a class that has integers, getter/setters, with input validation

Tags: java, class, integer, getter, setter

I am working on this Java program where I am supposed to write a class called kumquat that has an integer age with getter and setters. Additionally, I need to do input validation. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm sorry if this is really simple I'm just still really new to this.

```
public class Person
{
    private int age;
    
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    
    public void setAge(int newAge)
    {
        this.age = newAge;
    }
}
```

and then my main

```
public class Kumquat
{

    public static void main(int[] args)
    {
        Person myObj = new Person();
        myObj.setAge("5");
        System.out.println(myObj.getAge());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok in the `Person` class. Although in your `main` the method `Person::setAge` receives an `int` as parameter and you're trying to pass a `String` in line `myObj.setAge("5");`. Try passing an `int` like `myObj.setAge(5);` instead.

Comment: Duh of course! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should write String instead of int and setAge should not be string

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Person myObj = new Person();
    myObj.setAge(5);
    System.out.println(myObj.getAge());
}
```

Comment: While you are correct if this main method is intended to be the main method of the program. However your answer doesn't address the actual compile error that the OP is passing a string to `setAge` which is expecting and int.